# How to encrypt all data in a folder recursively?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I can use:

```
for f in .* ; do [ -f $f ] && openssl aes-256-cbc -in $f -out $f -k PASSWORD ; done
```

to encrypt all hidden files in a folder and use:

```
for f in * ; do [ -f $f ] && openssl aes-256-cbc -in $f -out $f -k PASSWORD ; done
```

to encrypt all visible files in a folder. Is it possible to combine these two commands? And are there other potential types of files that are not matched by `*` and `.*`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way run a command on each file in a directory tree](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99/best-way-run-a-command-on-each-file-in-a-directory-tree)

Comment: `*` isn't recursive. You'd need something like bash's `globstar` (`**`). Or just use `find`.

Comment: @muru can you write an answer using `find`? I also realized it isn't recursive but I am not sure how to use find with openssl particularly I don't know how to get `$f` from the original command.

Comment: `find . -type f -exec openssl aes-256-cbc -in {} -out {} -k PASSWORD \;` I'd expect. Though I am not certain writing to the same file works well with `openssl`. I think it truncates the output file immediately, so it will read from an empty file.

Comment: @muru you are right, it does read from an empty file...

Comment: Double-quote those variables when you use them (`"$f"` instead of `$f`)

Answer (score 0):

I use the && thing:

```
for f in .* ; do [ -f $f ] && openssl aes-256-cbc -in $f -out $f -k PASSWORD ; done && for f in * ; do [ -f $f ] && openssl aes-256-cbc -in $f -out $f -k PASSWORD ; done
```

Ex. echo 1 && echo 2 returns

1

2

Comment: This doesn’t do anything that couldn’t be done more simply by ```for f in .* * ; do …```. More importantly, this doesn’t work recursively.

Comment: Also -- if there is an error in one command, the next ones won't be executed.